# usb usb1-port7: unable to enumerate USB device

Tags: python

I am using Kali 2020.3. And I get this annoying kernel message "
usb usb1-port7: unable to enumerate USB device". And I've been trying to fix it to no avail. So can anyone help

Comment: Most likely a faulty USB device / cable and no programming issue.

Comment: Can this happen with out even attached usb cables

Comment: Please reconsider the last part of my first comment!